# Recommended way to issue multiple parallel REST calls and wait for all results in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request

I want to call several REST APIs to obtain data I use. I want all the REST calls to finish and then do some calculation. The code below works but I do not like it that much. Especially when one site returns an error it is not that easy to see where it come from. I would prefer to handle each call separately and then in the end "wait" for all calls to complete. That way I could also do a partial calculation if somehow one REST call did not work

```
const rp = require('request-promise');


var site1 = {
    uri: 'https://www.site1.com/api/v1/somedata.json',
    json: true
};


var site2 = {
    uri: 'https://www.site2.com/api/v1/somedata.json',
    json: true
};

var site3 = {
    uri: 'https://www.site3.com/api/v1/somedata.json',
    json: true
};


var promises = [];
promises.push(rp(site1));
promises.push(rp(site2));
promises.push(rp(site3));


Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // fetch all data from data variable and do calulation 
}, err => {
    console.log('error')
});
```

Comment: Promise.all is all or nothing. You need to handle them seperately.

Comment: You can use `Promise.allSettled()` which resolves once all the given promises are resolved or rejected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle each one individually as the results come in, you can add a `.then()` and/or `.catch()` handler for each one:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(rp(site1).then(result => {
    // do any partial processing
    return result;
}).catch(err => {
    // decide what to do if error
    throw err;
}));
promises.push(rp(site2).then(result => {
    // do any partial processing
    return result;
}).catch(err => {
    // decide what to do if error
    throw err;
}));
promises.push(rp(site3).then(result => {
    // do any partial processing
    return result;
}).catch(err => {
    // decide what to do if error
    throw err;
}));

Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // fetch all data from data variable and do calulation 
}, err => {
    console.log('error')
});
```

Of course, if the processing is identical for each request, then encapsulate that extra functionality in a function that calls `rp()` and then does the processing and you can then use that function instead of `rp()`.  So, it really depends upon exactly  what intermediate processing you want to do.

---

If the processing is identical, you can create your own wrapper function.  For example, supposed you wanted to just keep the processing going, even if error, you could do this:

```
function rpExtra(args) {
    return rp(args).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return null;   // sentinel resolved value to keep processing going for Promise.all()
    });
}

var promises = [];
promises.push(rpExtra(site1));
promises.push(rpExtra(site2));
promises.push(rpExtra(site3));


Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    // fetch all data from data variable and do calculation
    // skip any `null` values (those had errors) 
}, err => {
    console.log('error')
});
```

The details of exactly what to do for the error handling here is very situation-specific so I've given you the structure and you'd have to fill in what exactly you want to do.  A `.catch()` handler can either rethrow (to keep the promise rejects and have `Promise.all()` abort) or it can return a value (to change the promise to resolved and keep `Promise.all()` processing going).

Comment: @jaaph - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.